# How can I return data from MySQL as navbar links

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I want to return some data from my table as navbar links, my table holds this information:

[image: capture]

Then I coded this:

```
<?php 
$result = $db->query("SELECT * FROM topnav ORDER BY 'table_id' ASC");   
while($row = $result->fetch_object()){
    echo "
    <li><a href='contact.html'>".$row->name_link."</a></li>
    <li><a href='about.html'>".$row->name_link."</a></li>
    <li><a href='news.html'>".$row->name_link."</a></li>
    <li><a href='news.html'>".$row->name_link."</a></li>
    <li><a href='news.html'>".$row->name_link."</a></li>
    <li><a href='blog.html'>".$row->name_link."</a></li>
    <li class='active'><a href='index.html'>".$row->name_link."</a></li>
    ";  
}
?>
```

But this is wrong because it prints this as result:

[image: capture 2]

And I want each item to be printed once and then another `name_link` appears.

So how can I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming the value from `name_link` column is the same of html file, then:

```
<?php 
$result = $db->query("SELECT * FROM topnav ORDER BY 'table_id' ASC");   
while($row = $result->fetch_object()){
    echo "<li><a href='".$row->name_link.".html'>".$row->name_link."</a></li>";  
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

This would seem to be more like what you need - create one `<li>` per row returned from your table. (I've assumed `href-link` is the field in your table which should be used as the URL.)

```
<?php 
$result = $db->query("SELECT * FROM topnav ORDER BY 'table_id' ASC");   
while($row = $result->fetch_object()){
    echo "<li><a href='".$row->href_link."'>".$row->name_link."</a></li>";  
}
?>
```

What you were doing before is repeating your entire menu for every row in your table, which doesn't make any sense.